# Your work is improving all the time vs Your work improves all the time

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

> Your work is improving all the time

vs

> Your work improves all the time

Are both of these tenses ok to use in this sentence? Is there a slight difference in meaning?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can get the idea if you check some examples using [improve](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=improve).

Using *improve* as a transitive verb should need a direct object. But your example does not have one.
However intransitive verb usage does not have a direct object:

> 1. To become better: *Economic conditions **are improving***.

So I would use:

> Your work **is improving** all the time.